# Should a partition be a multiple of a specific amount of data space?

Tags: partitioning, ssd

When partitioning a SSD is there a favourable multiple of an amount of space or can you just use any size without a disadvantige in performance?

Comment: The size of your partition on a SSD makes no different on performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partition space is allocated start-to-end, not the other way around.

So if the *first* sector is offset (misaligned), then *all* sectors are also offset by the same amount. (Therefore each partition should start at a physical boundary – the exact multiple depends on your disk.)

But the *end* of the partition does not have any broad effect. If the partition ends in the middle of a physical block, it doesn't affect anything but a few sectors at the end (which are also very rarely written to, anyway). So the total size of a partition does not matter.

(I may be wrong here.)

Answer (score 2):

If you mean power of 2 (256, 512 etc) or something like that then I'd say no. In my experience no matter what size I used to partition my SSDs they always had good performance, few times I had low benchmarks on couple of drives but I exchanged them and new ones were fine. SSDs are designed to counter HDDs issue with moving head, they access data equally fast no matter where it is eliminating seek time delays. I don't see how size of partition can matter here.